# click on multiple buttons inorder with robotium not working

Tags: java, android, robotium

I am working an app with multiple Buttons to preinstalled apps on the phone (browser, phone, etc.) and I want robotium to test the app by clicking on each of them in order, go back to the application and then click the next button.

How can I do this?

What I did till now is the following code for each button:

```
public void testBrowser() throws Exception {
Log.i(TAG, "test browser");
Thread.sleep(2000);
solo.clickOnButton("Start Browser");
solo.assertCurrentActivity("Should be browser activity",MainActivity.class);
solo.takeScreenshot();
solo.goBack();
```

but it always does the first one and skips to the last one and it never closes it.

Comment: Are all the buttons tested inside one test method, or you have separate test methods for the other buttons? And can you clarify what you mean by "does the first one and skips to the last one"?

Comment: @DaveC yes. I have separate methods. and there are different methods for different buttons. What robotium does is click on the first button and then skip the middle once and click on the very last button. when what I want to do is click on each button and check whether it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to finish all your activities after each test run. Override the TestCase's tearDown method like this

```
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}
```